# how do whatsapp or other messaging apps run some task when the app is killed?

Tags: android, messaging, background-service

I have facing too much problem in this topic..

I tried it some ways like

1. combining Service, Broadcast Service & Foreground notification. In this case the service will run when app is killed but when i clear all apps from ram then the service is stopped permanently and not start again.
2. I also use Job scheduler but it run only when app is on foreground or in background but when app is killed then the task stopped.

I want some solution for android Oreo or above

**Please help me.....**

Comment: Is your service started as "START_STICKY"?!

Comment: @Farid yes my service started as "START_STICKY"

Comment: Take a look at WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
This handles running background tasks for you.

Comment: They use the FCM, so I recommend to use it too. Because WorkManagers, JobSchedulers and other services will be killed by Android after some time.

Comment: Thank you... I use WorkManager and FCM. it's work properly.